# Are there any lisp projects like jazz band?

Tags: package, package-repositories

I was curious is there anything like https://jazzband.co/ but for emacs lisp where you can submit packages so that they can be submitted / maintained by a group rather than an individual ?

Comment: To all forum participants, including the person who down-voted without providing any comment, please provide constructive criticism to help the O.P. improve upon the question, etc.  Down-voting without providing any input is a disservice to the Emacs community ...

Comment: I have my doubts this works with a community where only a very small part is cranking out packages. The Python community is far larger, the only similar thing I've seen for lisp is https://github.com/sharplispers.

Comment: awesome that looks like exactly the sort of thing I was looking for :)

Comment: FWIW, GNU ELPA's goal is somewhat similar.